# How to specify only the place but not the size of a tkinter window?

Tags: python, tkinter

Right now I'm using something like this to place my window:

```
def center_win(self):
    screen_width = self.master.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = self.master.winfo_screenheight()
    win_width = int(screen_width / 2)
    win_height = int(screen_height / 3)   
    x_pos = int((screen_width - win_width) / 2 )
    y_pos = int((screen_height - win_height) / 2)
    self.master.geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(win_width, win_height,
                                              x_pos, y_pos))
```

I'd like to give just the X and Y coordinates for the window, not the size. The size ist determined automatically by pack(), which is fine. Is there a way to only pass the x_pos and y_pos parameters to the .geometry method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure only set the `"+{}+{}"` part:

```
root.geometry("+{}+{}".format(256, 512))
#or more generally
#widget.winfo_toplevel().geometry("+{}+{}".format(256, 512))
```

Comment: Great! Works perfectly. Thanks!